# Upload video (chunks) using vimeo video upload api

Tags: php, laravel, upload, vimeo, blueimp

Hey i'm making a website for courses and i'am hosting my videos in vimeo and of course i want to send my file in chunks because when u upload large file it return error so how to upload large file in chunks to vimeo and how vimeo will know that this chunks belongs to each other .

Comment: What error does it return?

Comment: in my vimeo videos if i upload a video 20mb it divide video into two chunks and display the first 10mb and display error for the rest `VimeoUploadException in Vimeo.php line 417:
Error completing the upload.[Your video file is not valid. Either you have uploaded an invalid file format, or your upload is incomplete. Make sure you verify your upload before marking it as complete.`

Answer (score 0):

You should check with vimeo if they support chunked upload and how they receive chucked data, remember in blueimp jquery file upload there is special class for handling post data. Do vimeo has the same handling mechanism? check with them first and see if they support chucked and how they support it

Comment: I did not find any thing about that plus they did not talk about it i really do not what i have to do i used what they said and i added a video like 410mb and returned this error
after finishing uploading it display this error  `
VimeoRequestException in Vimeo.php line 154:
Unable to complete request.[Could not resolve host: 1511921153.cloud.vimeo.com]`